# Kafka serialization

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka

```
@Override
public byte[] serialize(String topic, EventLegalPlanInstanceLifecycleChange record) {
    return this.serializeImpl(this.getSubjectName(topic,this.isKey,record),record);
}
```

With the code above I'm getting the following error:

```
required: String,boolean,Object,ParsedSchema
found: String,boolean,EventLegalPlanInstanceLifecycleChange
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: You must pass a 4th argument to `this.serializeImpl` with the type of `ParsedSchema` to fit this method. If you don't have that value pass `null` instead. But be carefull with that since it might cause other errors!

Comment: check the args of getSubjectName method

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you're missing an instance of a `ParsedSchema`, which is a class from Confluent Schema Registry client.

If `EventLegalPlanInstanceLifecycleChange` is a generated class from Avro/Protobuf, then you shouldn't need to implement your own Serializer.